# A website a buy E-sim prototyping modules, for development purposes

Tags: rapid-prototyping, e-sim

I am building something of my own which requires an E-SIM integration. In order to go further with this I need to get a basic version on which I can conduct experiments. I want to ask you people that if any one of you could give me suggestion on which E-sim modules I should buy and where I can buy it from/ any site or something. I need a module that should be able to connect to IoT. I am open for each and every one of your views.

Answer (score 0):

I am not affiliated with these companies but they offer what you are looking for:

https://1ot.com/connectivity/esim

> 1. Request eSIM Test Kit (Give your contact details and receive eSIMs.)
> 2. Get access to 1oT Terminal (Once the SIMs arrive, you can activate them on 1oT Terminal.)
> 3. Test session with an expert (Test eSIM transactions to see if your cellular module supports eSIM.)
> 4. Go live with deployments (Let’s build a global rocketship together.)

https://www.libelium.com/libeliumworld/what-is-an-esim-and-why-should-your-iot-project-care-about-it/

> If eSIM is the solution for your IoT project, [contact us](https://www.libelium.com/contact/) to start the
> first steps.